# why do i get an runtime error with bar_index?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

```
structureLookback   = input(title="Lookback", type=input.integer, defval=7,  group=trs)
targetBarIndex      = input(title="Bar Index", type=input.integer, defval=0,  group=trs)


//bar_index low high


n = bar_index < targetBarIndex ? na : bar_index - targetBarIndex
pivotLowHigh = tradeType == "Long" ? (bar_index < targetBarIndex ? na : low[n]) : bar_index < targetBarIndex ? na : high[n]
    
//Fib Trailing variablen

var Price = 0.0
t_Price = tradeType == "Long" ? highest(high, structureLookback) : lowest(low, structureLookback)

//Berechnung des Fib-Levels

fib_m23 = Price-(Price-pivotLowHigh)*(-0.236)


//Update Price aufgrund von Price Action

if ((bar_index >= targetBarIndex and  targetBarIndex != 0)or targetBarIndex==0)
    //long version
    if (t_Price > Price or Price == 0.0) and tradeType == "Long"
        Price := t_Price
plot(pivotLowHigh, color=color.gray, title="SwingLow")
```

This part of the function to get my pivot low with a set bar index, works but after 10-20s i get an runtime error.

**Pine cannot determine the referencing length of a series. Try using max_bars_back**

why does this error accure? and any suggestions what i have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article explains it: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000587849

Basically its because you are using `low[n]` and  `high[n]` with some `n` that is unknown and might go outside history buffer of this variables. Did you try to play with `max_bars_back` parameter?

---

UPD:

When you calculating on bars with the low resolution, your barset number is bigger than 10001 it is impossible to use
something like low[targetBarIndex], where targetBarIndex = 10000, because max history length of series variables is 10000.
You need to rewrite your script.

1. I suggest you to add additional condition which will make your script to calculate only around desired `targetBarIndex` (`if bar_index > targetBarIndex and bar_index<targetBarIndex+2` ), because, as I see,  `pivotLowHigh` value calculating only in this area.

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=false, margin_long=100, margin_short=100, max_bars_back = 5000)
structureLookback   = input(title="Lookback", type=input.integer, defval=7)
targetBarIndex      = input(title="Bar Index", type=input.integer, defval=0)

tradeType = "Long"
// //bar_index low high
var float pivotLowHigh = na
var int n = na

if bar_index > targetBarIndex and bar_index<targetBarIndex+2
    n := bar_index - targetBarIndex
    pivotLowHigh := tradeType == "Long" ? low[n] : high[n]
    
    
//Fib Trailing variablen

var Price = 0.0
t_Price = tradeType == "Long" ? highest(high, structureLookback) : lowest(low, structureLookback)

//Berechnung des Fib-Levels

fib_m23 = Price-(Price-pivotLowHigh)*(-0.236)


//Update Price aufgrund von Price Action

if ((bar_index >= targetBarIndex and  targetBarIndex != 0)or targetBarIndex==0)
    //long version
    if (t_Price > Price or Price == 0.0) and tradeType == "Long"
        Price := t_Price
plot(pivotLowHigh, color=color.gray, title="SwingLow")
```

2. Second approach, if you really need to calculate past values in the every bar, then you can use arrays to push `high` and `low` values, and calculate values from them. Array size can be 10 times bigger than the history of the serial variable.

Comment: i tryed using it but do not understand how it works. There are several methods to implement, which one is the right and how do i use it right?

Comment: Pls provide more of your code, I'll help you

Comment: i did edit more code, thank you.

Comment: Updated answer.